# Как полностью настраивать форму Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть форма для создания Тренировки, как эту форму можно выводить помимо {{ form }}

Ещё хотелось бы узнать, как настраивать эту форму? Допустим input хочу поставить свой, как передавать данные из input`a уже для сохранения в бд, по name или id? Очень много вопросов. Кто сможет скинуть документации, буду очень благодарен!